# Mysql Server shuts down periodically on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql Server shuts down periodically on Ubuntu.  I looked through the system log file and found the following lines in the log files i checked :

```
 Out of memory: Kill process 719 (mysqld) score 114 or sacrifice child
```

We are however using just about 20% of the allocated memory.

What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Is the MySQL server a 32-bit binary that runs into the 2 GB limit of 32-bit apps?

Comment: @aeyoun please, how do i verify this?

Comment: You can run `file $(which mysqld)` and see whether the output mentions x86-64 or i386.

Comment: it reads ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xba5b9662c68585316ea5538b55184861e228eb22, stripped

Comment: Then that is your problem. You need to install a 64-bit server on a 64-bit system to allow a single process to use more memory.

Comment: @Aeyoun switched to a 64-bit server, output of file $(which mysqld) is  ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x39a6f6f18f27252300802187f87abcedc6476c7f, stripped, problem however persists

Answer (score 0):

It says what is wrong right in the error message. It is out of memory.

It could be a 32-bit application with 2–3 GB memory restriction that 32-bit apps have. You can run file $(which mysqld) and see whether the output mentions x86-64 or 32-bit/i386.

Or there could be a upper limit on the server. Check the configuration in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and look at the upper memory limits.

Answer (score 0):

It's also always a good idea to check for the biggest tables or tables with the biggest overhead via localhost/phpmyadmin (if installed). Sometimes it's just a matter of cleaning the caches of a cms (if you're using mysql for a CMS) and looking for overhead and get rid of it via phpmyadmin

additionally if this helps and your are using mysql for a cms that is causing the problems it might be necessary to check the caching policies and setup a cron job to clean caches periodically